# adding in error control to to .when.then and xdr request

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i have some code that goes and gets a json file and from that it passes it to a bootstrap page that kicks my app into life

so I have a function that goes and gets the file and returns a callback

```
function makeCorsRequest(method, url, callbackFunction)
        {
            if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
                var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                xdr.open(method, url);
                xdr.onload = function() {
                    var JSON = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
                    if (JSON == null || typeof (JSON) == 'undefined')
                    {
                        JSON = $.parseJSON(data.firstChild.textContent);
                    }
                    window[callbackFunction](JSON);
                };
                xdr.onprogress = function() {};
                xdr.send();
            } else {
                var promise = $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: method,
                    dataType: 'json'
                });

                $.when(promise).then(function(result) {
                    window[callbackFunction](result);
                });
            }
        }
```

and then some code that calls it

```
$(document).ready(function() {           
   makeCorsRequest('GET', '/data/data.json', 'processData');
});
```

this works and when the json is returned the processData is run, but i need some error handling to deal with when the json cant be loaded and processData isnt run..

what could be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `$.when` -> `$.then` as you can use .done() and .fail() callbacks provided by `promise`

```
promise.done(function (result) {
    //success callback
    window[callbackFunction](result);
}).fail(function(){
    //error callback
});
```

Comment: cool and what about the ie part? i was think .done and .fail but not sure about that but

Comment: it doesnt even get as far as var JSON = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText); if there is an error

Comment: @Dan you are using using a different code of IE... is there a specific reason

Comment: yes because the i am getting the json files from amazon and need to use a CORS request

Answer (score 0):

```
 function makeCorsRequest(method, url, callbackFunction)
        {
            if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
                var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                    if (xdr) {

                        xdr.open(method, url);
                        xdr.onerror = function() { alert("Data cannot be loaded at this time. Please ensure there are not ad blockers enabled.");};
                        xdr.onload = function() {
                            var JSON = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);

                            if (JSON == null || typeof (JSON) == 'undefined')
                            {
                                JSON = $.parseJSON(data.firstChild.textContent);
                            }                   
                            window[callbackFunction](JSON);
                        };
                        xdr.onprogress = function() {};
                        xdr.send();
                    }
            } else {
                var promise = $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: method,
                    dataType: 'json'
                });

                promise.done(function (result) {
                    window[callbackFunction](result);
                }).fail(function(){
                    alert("Data cannot be loaded at this time. Please ensure there are not ad blockers enabled.");  
                });


            }
        }
```